# "Capture" variables in lambda function parsed as argument

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

*I have no idea what to title this question as, sorry.*

---

I have a function in C++ which takes a lambda as a parameter.

```
void LoopPixels(cv::Mat &img, void(*fptr)(uchar &r, uchar &g, uchar &b)) {
    // ...
    fptr(r, g, b); // Call the lambda function
}
```

Then I am trying to call this `LoopPixels` function.

```
int threshold = 50;
LoopPixels(img, [](uchar &r, uchar &g, uchar &b) {
    r *= (uchar)threshold; // Unable to access threshold :(
});
```

My problem is, I cannot access the `threshold` variable from inside the lambda function, and if I try to *"catch"* it with `[&threshold](uchar &r...){}`, I receive an error telling me the lambda I parsed into `LoopPixels` is of the wrong type.

Error message:

> no suitable conversion function from "lambda []void (uchar &r, uchar
>   &g, uchar &b)->void" to "void (*)(uchar &r, uchar &g, uchar &b)"
>   exists

**How can I access variables within a lambda which has been parsed as a function argument?**

Comment: Only lambdas that capture nothing can be cast to a function pointer. Change your function to a template and the function pointer into a template argument.

Comment: Okay, I've changed my function to

`template <class T>
void LoopPixels(cv::Mat &img, T *fptr)`

and I'm getting `Couldn't match type 'T*' against <lambda>`

Comment: You pass a lambda, not a pointer. hence the error message.

Comment: *"which takes a lambda as a parameter."*. No, your function take function pointer (and capture-less lambda can convert to that).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot pass a capturing lambda to a function pointer. You have to change the function to use a [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), or use a function template.

```
void LoopPixels1(cv::Mat &img, std::function<void(uchar &r, uchar &g, uchar &b)> fn);
// Or:
template<typename Callable>
void LoopPixels2(cv::Mat &img, Callable fn);

// Can be called with a capturing lambda
LoopPixels1(img, [threshold](uchar &r, uchar &g, uchar &b) { });
LoopPixels2(img, [threshold](uchar &r, uchar &g, uchar &b) { });
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of how I could call `LoopPixels` please.

Comment: Worth to mention:  with the first option, don't forget to include header `<functional>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this:

```
void LoopPixels(cv::Mat& img, uint& r, uint& g, uint& b, const std::function<void(uint& r, uint& g, uint& b)>& callback)
{
    callback(r, g, b);
}

cv::Mat img;
int threshold = 50;
uint r = 1;
uint g = 1;
uint b = 1;

std::cout << "(before) rgb : " << r << g << b << std::endl;

LoopPixels(img, r, g, b, [threshold](uint& r, uint& g, uint& b)
{
   r *= threshold;
   g *= threshold;
   b *= threshold;
});

std::cout << "(after) rgb : " << r << g << b << std::endl;
```

The lamba capture is passed by value because the reference could go out of scope before the callback call.

(I used uint for r, g, b variables instead of uchar because multiplying a uchar for an int might not give the result you expect).